# How to make ndgrid work with 1-dimensional data in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, is-empty

First of all, I could not find a better title to describe my problem, sorry for that. Maybe someone could suggest a better title.

I have the following code:

```
gridSize = (gridResolution - 1) .* gridStepSize;
positionsVectorY = gridSize(1) / 2 : -gridStepSize(1) : -gridSize(1) / 2;
positionsVectorX = -gridSize(2) / 2 : gridStepSize(2) : gridSize(2) / 2;
[ gridPositionMatrixY, gridPositionMatrixX ] = ndgrid(positionsVectorY, positionsVectorX);
```

This code works fine for me if `gridSize(1)` > 0, `gridSize(2)` > 0 and if `gridResolution(1)` > 1, `gridResolution(2)` > 1. However, if  that is not the case, the matrix / matrices are empty. For example, `[y, x] = ndgrid([], 1 : 3)` returns empty matrices: `Empty matrix: 0-by-3`. What I would need in that case is `[y, x] = ndgrid(0, 1 : 3)`.

So, my question is: What is the best way to change the above code to create the desired matrices?

I could simply check if `positionsVectorY` is empty and replace it with zeros. But I'm wondering if there is a more "elegant" solution to this.

Thank you,

Adrian

**EDIT: An example:**

Here is an example where my code works:

```
positionsVectorY = 1 : 2;
positionsVectorX = 1 : 3;
[y, x] = ndgrid(positionsVectorY, positionsVectorX)
```

The output is

```
y =

     1     1     1
     2     2     2


x =

     1     2     3
     1     2     3
```

And here is a special case where it does not work: If the resolution in y direction is 1, and the size of the grid is 0 in y direction, then my code generates an empty array `positionsVectorY`. Then:

```
positionsVectorY = []; 
positionsVectorX = 1 : 3;
[y, x] = ndgrid(positionsVectorY, positionsVectorX)
```

The output is:

```
y =

   Empty matrix: 0-by-3


x =

   Empty matrix: 0-by-3
```

That is not what I want, I want that my code generates

```
positionsVectorY = 0;    % instead  of [] 
positionsVectorX = 1 : 3;
[y, x] = ndgrid(positionsVectorY, positionsVectorX)
```

in this special case, with the output:

```
y =

     0     0     0


x =

     1     2     3
```

What I want in the end, is to modify my code so it works for the general case, but also for the special case where the resolution in y or x direction can be 1. My temporary solution is using if-statements,

```
if(isempty(positionsVectorY))
    positionsVectorY = 0;
end

if(isempty(positionsVectorX))
    positionsVectorX = 0;
end
```

But I would like to remove them and do it in a more elegant way.

Comment: why do you want to make a data structure for a grid of size zero? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: My code works with 4 dimensional data (not shown here) and I would like to visualize some things. For this, I need to drop some dimensions. I would set the resolution for one dimension to 1, and for this special case the above code needs to be adapted.

Comment: `ndgrid` works by generating coordinates in N dimensions.  If you want to do it with 1 dimension, why don't you try using `linspace` and `repmat`?  I also don't quite understand what you want.  Can you show us an example of what the output would look like?

Comment: @rayryeng Yes I could do that, but I want to keep my code general enough so I can dynamically choose the dimensions from outside. Also, I want to avoid if statements. I will add an example to make it more clear what I need.

Comment: I edited the question to make an explicit example.

Comment: @aeduG - Given your use case, personally the best way is to check if it's empty as how you're doing it.  Right now, code things to get it to work.  Only modify things if you can quantifiably measure "elegance" or efficiency.  If the above works, and if it's fast, then why don't you just leave it?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. I just hoped there is a command in matlab that does it in one line or so, but I will leave it this way for now. Thanks for the help!